# How to get build status of PR using BitBucket API?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, github-api, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

Not getting Build job details/status of the PR when using Bitbucket API for any pull request

Here is my API URL:

```
https://example.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectkey}/repos/{reposlug}/pull-requests/{pullrequestID}
```

How Build status looks like on GUI:

[image]

I also tried below methods to get the Build status but no luck

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/settings/pull-requests
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/settings/hooks
```

So I wanted to get whether build status of any PR whether it is Success or Fail

Thanks in Advance for your answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The build status is on the commit, not on the PR. First you should find the latest commit of the source branch by calling `/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests/{pullRequestId}`. see the [docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/6.6.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp270) for more details

Once you have the commit id you can query the build-status api by calling `/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/{commitId}`. See the [docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/6.6.1/bitbucket-build-rest.html#idp1) for more details

Answer (score 3):

Using API 2.0

- Get statuses: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests/%7Bpull_request_id%7D/statuses
- Set status: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commit/%7Bnode%7D/statuses/build

Example:

```sh
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/piavita/com.piavita-vet.ios/pullrequests/300/statuses \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic SecretKey' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/piavita/com.piavita-vet.ios/commit/8619291af393/statuses/build \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic SecretKey' \
  --header 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  --data '{\n   "url": "http://jenkins.ddns.net:8080/job/jobName/123/",\n   "state": "SUCCESSFUL",\n    "key": "JENKINS"\n}'
```

Comment: if you're on a server/data-centre instance you would be stuck to API v1.0